# How do I solve this geometry problem related to circles?

Tags: geometry, circles

Line segment AB is an external tangent to circle O and circle Q at points A and B.  Radii lengths for circle O and circle Q are 4 and 9, respectively.  Find AB

Picture: https://ibb.co/hQ3ysb

How would I solve this problem?  Please include all steps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image: Here is how I tried to draw.]

$AO \bot OCQ$ and $BO \bot OCQ$
Draw $AD$ 
Then $AOQD$ becomes a *rectangle*
Therefore, $AD=OQ= 4+9= 13$
Then in $rt \triangle ADB$, 
By *Pythagorean theorem*
$ AB^2 = 13^2 + (9-4)^2$

Comment: Sorry for my pic, I'm still not good at it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Pythagorean theorem
is always recommended
when there are right triangles.